# Are there any performance penalties by using nested Conditional Operator?

Tags: verilog

Here is an [example](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00010.htm) that use nested conditional operator to map register address to it's value.

```
reg [4:0] mux;
reg [1:0] addr;
mux = (addr == 2'b00) ? i0 :
  ((addr == 2'b01) ? i1 :
  ((addr == 2'b10) ? i2 :
  ((addr == 2'b11) ? i3 :
  4'bz)));
```

In my application, there are about one hundred registers, so The nested level is very deep. If the expression is C language executed by CPU, it will be very slow.

How about FPGA?

Comment: It will cost you extra hardware and you might become concerned about the delay between the logic gates.

Comment: It'd be better to use `case` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, it depends on the synthesizer as well as the options used. It can use your code as a functional guideline to generate equivalent logic. Or it can use it as a structural guideline in which case each `?:` conditional operator is mapped to a 2:1 mux. You can do experiments with your synthesizer to figure how how the generate the gate equivalent, and read the synthesis options in the manual.

Generally I use the `?:` conditional operator when I intentionally want a 2:1 mux (or tri-state driver). For more complex conditional multiplexing, I prefer using case statements or if-else statements. This strategy usually fulfills timing and area requirements.

With large multiplexing (you mentioned "about one hundred registers"), meeting timing and area requirements can be difficult. Sometimes the synthesizer can handle this, other times it needs more guidance. Synthesizer directives (refer to manual) and splitting the multiplexer into chunks is one way to deal with it. Your FPGA may have a macro module of dedicated logic (RAMs, complex arithmetic logic, etc) you could instantiate to substitute for portions of your code.

Comment: I found [this tutorial](http://electrosofts.com/verilog/mux.html), it has used seven different ways to implement a 4 to 1 MUX. Do you think Example III and Example IV is better than Example V for my 100 to 1 MUX case?

Comment: @HYRY , yes, I recommend III and IV over V. Example I and II can work if it the array depth is a power of 2. All the examples are functionally the same, area and timing may differ for synthesis; plus the ease of code flexibility and readability.

Comment: FYI: The examples from the link use Verilog-95 coding style. It valid, however the Verilog-2001 style is preferred with ANSI header style and auto sensitivity lists (`@*` or `@(*)`) for combinational logic. I suggest looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case of your example most synthesizers will interpret this as a series of 2-to-1 multiplexers.

In a more general case such as

```
output = (one_condition)? a : (another_condition)? b : (other_condition)? c : ...
```

It will use a multiplexer for each condition extending the asynchronous path. A longer asynchronous path means a longer settling time and slower maximum clock frequency.

Comment: I think, it will be synthesized as series of 2*1 mux. Because nested conditional operators inherently have priority.

Comment: @KaranShah I thought the synthesizer was smarter than that but I checked some Xilinx application notes, and found no clue. I think you're right. I'm correcting the answer.